# change a previous uploaded project from objective c to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

My friend uploaded a project to app store and it's already in objective c and has my clients. Now I'm converting to Swift and I want to upload it to app store and I want my clients to receive my updated Swift project. Is this possible ? if so please guide me how to do it.

Comment: Are they the same bundle id (and account)?  If so, it should just work.

Comment: So i should just convert it to Swift then archive it and send the file to my friend he uploads it as a new version , right ?

Comment: If everything else is OK, changing the source language won't make a difference.  By the time it's compiled, the source isn't part of the package anyway.

Comment: I'll do it in my laptop and archive it and send it to my friend to upload it. How can I use same bundle id and I'm creating a new project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple identifies an app with its bundle identifier.
If you maintain the same bundle identifier in your new swift project, then users will receive update on the same app itself.

You can update it in Target > Build Settings > Bundle Identifier
[image]